# Custom Data Types for DataFrame columns when using Spark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I know I can use a custom dialect for having a correct mapping between my db and spark but how can I create a custom table schema with specific field data types and lengths when I use spark's `jdbc.write` options? I would like to have granular control over my table schemas when I load a table from spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minimal flexibility for writes, implemented by

- [SPARK-10101 - Spark JDBC writer mapping String to TEXT or VARCHAR](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10101)
- [SPARK-10849 - Allow user to specify database column type for data frame fields when writing data to jdbc data sources](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10849)

but if you want

> to have granular control over my table schemas when I load a table from spark.

you might have to implement your own [`JdbcDialect`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d4107196d59638845bd19da6aab074424d90ddaf/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L60). It is internal developer API and as far as I can tell it is not plugable so you may need customized Spark binaries (it might be possible to [`registerDialect`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d4107196d59638845bd19da6aab074424d90ddaf/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L181-L183) but I haven't tried this).

Answer (score 1):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

You can use the createTableColumnTypes option.

Here is the example from the documentation.

## Specifying create table column data types on write

```
jdbcDF.write \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(64), comments VARCHAR(1024)") \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})
```