# Spark SQL - Cast to UUID of the Dataset Column throws Parse Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Dataset<Row> finalResult = df.selectExpr("cast(col1 as uuid())", "col2");
```

When we tried to cast the Column in the dataset to UUID and persist in Postgres, i see the following exception. Please suggest the alternate solution to convert the column in a data set to UUID.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
DataType uuid() is not supported.(line 1, pos 21)

== SQL ==
cast(col1 as UUID)
---------------------^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark has no uuid type, so casting to one is just not going to work.

You can try to use `database.column.type` metadata property as explained in [Custom Data Types for DataFrame columns when using Spark JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47636867) and [SPARK-10849](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10849).

Comment: i tried  MetadataBuilder and it was not working. I found the work aroud, please find my answer here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625460/