# It is possible to write to MySQL columns of type MEDIUMTEXT in Spark?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading into a data frame using Spark SQL from a MySQL table where a column has type `MEDIUMTEXT`. When I write the data frame into a new table unmodified, that column now has type `TEXT` and I get a MySQL `MysqlDataTruncation` exception.

I'm unable to figure out if I'm out of luck or there's some way to inform Spark SQL what the desired MySQL-specific result column type is.

Does anyone here know something about this issue?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7 and Spark 2.4.3.

Comment: I asked that because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397/3986005). It could be a unicode issue.

Comment: Interesting - thanks, didn't see that before. I just tried to run read and write against MySQL 8.0 and the problem still appears. Also, I would be surprised if it was unicode, since all the data to be written comes from similar MySQL server.

Comment: I assumed you realized that a `MEDIUMTEXT` (16,777,215 characters) is a lot bigger than a `TEXT` (65,535 characters). Perhaps you didn't? See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html Just test the maximum length of the text column to see if that's the problem.

Comment: My problem is exactly because of that difference. My source column is of type `MEDIUMTEXT` and the target column (created by Spark) is type `TEXT`, which produces a `MysqlDataTruncation` error when Spark tries to insert the data - and I'm looking for a way to get Spark to create a column of type `MEDIUMTEXT`. I'll provide some code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: It is probably better to ask a new question, with more information than the current one, because only a few people will look at a week old question. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47637072/3986005) from 2017, perhaps it is useful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`createTableColumnTypes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to custom the column type instead of the defaults in SparkSQL.

Of cause, you can't use `MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT` directly, if you witre code like this:

```scala
// Saving data to a JDBC source
// Suppose column "name" is the column which you want to write as type MEDIUMTEXT
jdbcDF.write
  .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name MEDIUMTEXT")
  .jdbc("jdbc://...", "xxx tablename", ...)
```

maybe you will get a exception like this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
DataType MEDIUMTEXT is not supported.(line 1, pos 12)

== SQL ==
name MEDIUMTEXT
-----^^^

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitPrimitiveDataType$1(AstBuilder.scala:1772)
...
```

But MySQL can auto convert column type from `VARCHAR(n > 65535)` to `MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT` when you disable the SQL MODE `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` in `my.cnf`.
So you can wirte code like this:

```scala
// the length of column "name" over the limit of VARCHAR(65535)，
// it will be auto converted to MEDIUMTEXT
jdbcDF.write
  .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name VARCHAR(65536)")
  .jdbc("jdbc://...", "xxx tablename", ...)
```

Then MySQL will create a table with column "name" which  type is MEDIUMTEXT.